# Can't split each element of string to a new lines

Tags: python

I have a problem to split each element of string into new lines using class.

I have to define my own class Songs and I have to use into this class _ _ init _ _ which should contain arguments: self, lyrics. Into that class I have to create method sing_me which is going to split every element of string (Songs) into new lines.

Output should look like:
When it"s black,
Take a little time to hold yourself,
Take a little time to feel around,
Before it"s gone!

I have to contain this line in main function and the goal is to split every element of Songs to a new line.

```
Let_go = Songs(['When it"s black, ', 'Take a little time to hold yourself, ', 'Take a little time to feel around, ', 'Before it"s gone!'])
```

I tried many solutions to make it work but I have no idea how to solve that problem.

```
class Songs:
    def __init__(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics
    def sing_me(self):
        # Tried both solutions but any of them aren't working
        # print("\n".join(self.lyrics))
        # for line in self.lyrics: print(line)

def main():
    Let_go = Songs(['When it"s black, ', 'Take a little time to hold yourself, ', 'Take a little time to feel around, ', 'Before it"s gone!'])  
    # Here are my tries:
    # Let_go.sing_me()
    # Let_go = Songs.sing_me((['When it"s black, ', 'Take a little time to hold yourself, ', 'Take a little time to feel around, ', 'Before it"s gone!']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your original code with the for loop and it worked like you asked:

```
class Songs:
    def __init__(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_me(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Let_go = Songs(['When it"s black, ', 'Take a little time to hold yourself, ',
                    'Take a little time to feel around, ', 'Before it"s gone!'])
        # Here are my tries:
        # Let_go.sing_me()
        # Let_go = Songs.sing_me((['When it"s black, ', 'Take a little time to hold yourself, ', 'Take a little time to feel around, ', 'Before it"s gone!']))
    Let_go.sing_me()
```

output:

```
When it"s black, 
Take a little time to hold yourself, 
Take a little time to feel around,
Before it"s gone!
```

Answer (score 1):

It'a actually quite simple:

```py
class Songs:
    def __init__(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics
    def sing_me(self):
        #print each element of list on a new line
        for i in self.lyrics:
            print(i)      


def main():
    Let_go = Songs(['When it"s black, ', 'Take a little time to hold yourself, ', 'Take a little time to feel around, ', 'Before it"s gone!'])  
    Let_go.sing_me()
```